# Is there a built in method that can discard one part of an element for a particular index in an array?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating this game where I need to compare Player1 and Player2's cards which are stored in an array.

Each card, representing one element in the array, consists of a value (1-30) and a colour (RED,BLACK or YELLOW).

My task is to compare both the colour of each card and the value of each card separately- but what built in method should I use to only focus on either the colour or the value of an element?

Here is my code:

```
colours = ['RED','BLACK','YELLOW']
deck = [(random.randint(1,31),random.choice(colours)) for _ in range(30)]
random.shuffle(deck) 

def Player1_Cards(deck):
    return deck[:15]   #Player1 takes the first 15 cards from the array deck     
def Player2_Cards(deck): #Player2 takes the last 15 cards from the array deck
    return deck[15:]

print('Player 1`s cards are :',Player1_Cards(deck))
print('Player 2`s cards are :',Player2_Cards(deck))

#Here's what the array of Player1's Cards looks like:
[(5, 'BLACK'), (4, 'RED'), (31, 'YELLOW'), (27, 'RED'), (19, 'RED'), (6, 'YELLOW'), (11, 'YELLOW'), (17, 'BLACK'), (15, 'RED'), (20, 'BLACK'), (13, 'BLACK'), (9, 'RED'), (30, 'YELLOW'), (9, 'YELLOW'), (20, 'YELLOW')]
```

Comment: what type of compare are you looking tok do?

Comment: Whatever comparison you are trying to make I would suggest moving it to ```numpy``` (along with generation of random variables).